# Comparing maxVal's from OpenCV matchTemplate for dynamic template matching

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, template-matching

I am trying to do some dynamic template matching with `cv2.matchTemplate`. The template is:
[image]

and the image I am matching it to is:
[image]

I am adjusting the size and angle of the template and then grabbing `maxVal` and `maxLoc` from `cv2.matchTemplate` and storing them in a `dict` with `maxVal` as the keys. I'm then grabbing `max(data.keys())` as the "best" match from `result = cv2.matchTemplate(image, resized_template, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)`. When I loop through all of the keys and plot them on the image, there are some that find the mickey head much better than `max(data.keys())`.

This is the region for "best" match:

```
#Find best match from scores
best_match = max(scores.keys())
#Output image
image_copy = color_image.copy()
#Create rectangle around best match
cv2.rectangle(image_copy, (data[best_match][1][0], data[best_match][1][1]), (data[best_match][1][0] + data[best_match][0][0], data[best_match][1][1] + data[best_match][0][1]), (255, 255, 255), 2)
plt.imshow(image_copy)
```

[image]

But this region appears to locate it much more accurately:

```
image_copy = color_image.copy()
for n in list(data.keys())[69:70:1]:
    #Create rectangle around best match
    cv2.rectangle(image_copy, (data[n][1][0], data[n][1][1]), (data[n][1][0] + data[n][0][0], data[n][1][1] + data[n][0][1]), (255, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.imwrite('output_1.jpg', image_copy)
    plt.imshow(image_copy)
```

[image]

Am I miss interpreting what the `maxVal` from `cv2.matchTemplate` actually represents? If so, how can I select the actual "best" region based on some value or criteria? Here's the full code:

```
#Import packages 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import cv2
import imutils
import os

#Import template
template = cv2.imread(templates_dir + '\\' + os.listdir(templates_dir)[3])
gray_template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

#Import image
image = cv2.imread(images_dir + '\\' + os.listdir(images_dir)[5])
color_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

#Image dims
image_h = image.shape[1]
image_w = image.shape[0]

#Processing loop scaling the template
#Scores dict
scores = {}
#Data dict of structure (maxVal: (template dims, locs, angle))
data = {}

#Edge images 
template = cv2.Canny(gray_template, 80, 200)
image = cv2.Canny(gray_image, 80, 200)

#Loop through different template scales
for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.5, 15):
    #Loop through different template rotations
    for angle in np.linspace(0, 360, 25)[:-1]:
        #Rotate template
        template_rotated = imutils.rotate(template, angle)
        #Resize template
        resized_template = imutils.resize(template_rotated, width = int(template_rotated.shape[0] * scale))
        #Dims of resized template
        template_h = resized_template.shape[1]
        template_w = resized_template.shape[0]
        #Break from loop if the template becomes bigger than the image
        if template_h > image_h or template_w > image_w:
            break
        #Run template through image
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(image, resized_template, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
        #Get matching score and location
        (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
        #Add correlation value and result to scores
        scores[str(maxVal)] = result
        #Add info to data
        data[str(maxVal)] = ((template_h, template_w), (maxLoc[0], maxLoc[1]), angle)
    
#Find best match from scores
best_match = max(scores.keys())

#Output image
image_copy = color_image.copy()
#Create rectangle around best match
cv2.rectangle(image_copy, (data[best_match][1][0], data[best_match][1][1]), (data[best_match][1][0] + data[best_match][0][0], data[best_match][1][1] + data[best_match][0][1]), (0, 0, 255), 2)
plt.imshow(image_copy)
```